# Connect edge.js + node-webkit

Tags: c#, f#, node-webkit, edge.js

[Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) connects node.js and .NET. [Node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) is an app runtime based on Chromium and node.js. Has anybody put these two together? Is it possible?

Explanation: I would like to write apps with front-end in HTML + Typescript and back-end in F# (heavy computations etc.).

Comment: I havent but Im planning something that uses node-webkit with Edge.js + edge-fs compiler.  See http://7sharpnine.com/posts/i-node-something/ for reference.

Comment: Try to [build it](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#building) using [nw-gyp](https://github.com/rogerwang/nw-gyp) instead of node-gyp.

Comment: I'm trying to do this now but am having issues. Edge needs to be recompiled with nw-gyp but I have not been able yet to get it to work. After recompilation NW crashes when requiring the module.

Comment: I've filed a bug report on the node-webkit github page. https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1332

Comment: Have you been able to successfully integrate edgejs + nodewebkit + .Net?